# Stop fixed element scrolling at certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fixed position nav that fades in at a set scroll point.

I now need to stop it scrolling just before the page footer (about 400px from the bottom). I know the way to do this would be to change the position from fixed to absolute but I'm not sure how to implement that through jquery?

[Live Example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur930b6p/)

jQuery:

```
var isVisible = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var shouldBeVisible = $(window).scrollTop()>1000;
        if (shouldBeVisible && !isVisible) {
        isVisible = true;
    $('#floatingnav').fadeIn('slow');
    } else if (isVisible && !shouldBeVisible) {
        isVisible = false;
        $('#floatingnav').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#floatingnav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: you should structure your html so the floating nav is just above your footer so when you scroll down far enough you can just remove the position fixed

Comment: ($(window).scrollTop() < ($(window).height() - 1000) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the bottom position of the navigation is below the footer top position. If this is the case, set a class or a specific css-prop.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var windowTopPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var footerTopPos = $('#footer').offset().top;
  var navBottomPos = $('#floatingnav').offset().top + $('#floatingnav').outerHeight();

  if(navBottomPos >= footerTopPos) {
    $('#floatingnav').css('position', 'absolute');
  }
});
```